# Solidity Compile error for adding _studentLastName object

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, undeclared-identifier

Getting this compile error message for adding __studentLastName object:

contracts/scorecard.sol:44:42: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
studentObj.studentLastName = _studentLastName;

This is the solidity code -

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >= 0.4.0 <0.9.0;

contract Scorecard{

    uint256 studentCount = 0;
    address public classTeacher;

    constructor() public {
        classTeacher = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyClassTeacher(address _classTeacher) {
        require(classTeacher == _classTeacher, "Only the class teacher has access to this function");
        _;
    }

    struct StudentDetails{
        string studentFirstName;
        string studentLastName;
        uint256 id;
    }

    struct Score{
        uint256 studentId;
        uint256 englishMarks;
        uint256 mathMarks;
        uint256 scienceMarks;

    }

    mapping(uint => StudentDetails) students;

    mapping(uint => Score) scores;

    event studentAdded(string _studentFirstName, string _studentLastName, uint256 _studentId);

    event studentScoresRecorded(uint256 _studentId, uint256 _englishMarks, uint256 _mathMarks, uint256 _scienceMarks);

    function addStudentDetails (string memory _studentFirstName) public onlyClassTeacher(msg.sender){
        StudentDetails storage studentObj = students[studentCount];

        studentObj.studentFirstName = _studentFirstName;
        studentObj.studentLastName = _studentLastName;
        studentObj.id = studentCount;
        emit studentAdded(_studentFirstName, _studentLastName, msg.value, studentCount);
        studentCount++;
    }

    function addStudentScores(uint256 _studentId,
                              uint256 _englishMarks,
                              uint256 _mathMarks,
                              uint256 _scienceMarks ) public onlyClassTeacher(msg.sender){

        Score storage scoreObject = scores[_studentId];

        scoreObject.englishMarks = _englishMarks;
        scoreObject.mathMarks = _mathMarks;
        scoreObject.scienceMarks = _scienceMarks;
        scoreObject.studentId = _studentId;
        emit studentScoresRecorded(_studentId, _englishMarks, _mathMarks, _scienceMarks);
                              }
```

}

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. `addStudentDetails` function should declare `_studentLastName` before using it.
2. `studentAdded` emitter should have 4 parameters
3. `msg.sender` can't be passed to an unpayable function.

```
function addStudentDetails (string memory _studentFirstName, string memory _studentLastName) public onlyClassTeacher(msg.sender){
            StudentDetails storage studentObj = students[studentCount];
    
            studentObj.studentFirstName = _studentFirstName;
            studentObj.studentLastName = _studentLastName;
            studentObj.id = studentCount;
            emit studentAdded(_studentFirstName, _studentLastName, msg.sender, studentCount);
            studentCount++;
        }
```

Comment: THIS DOESN'T ANSWER THE QUESTION.  NOW IT TELLS ME IT IS ONLY EXPECTING 4 ARGUMENTS, BUT RECEIVED 3.  I DO NOT SEE HOW YOU ARE HELPING RESOLVE THE ISSUE. YOU OBVIOUSLY DIDN'T COMPILE THE CODE.  DON'T ANSWER THE QUESTION IF YOU ARE NOT GOING TO ACTUALLY GIVE A SOLUTION THAT WORKS.  I THOUGHT THAT WAS A GIVEN ON THIS PLATFORM, BUT...

Comment: @Shawngilbert107 The compilation error is you haven't provided the 4th parameter that's why you are facing the compilation issue have run it on remix after adding the 4th parameter it worked fine

Comment: What are you expecting more ?

Comment: I don't understand where I am supposed to be adding the parameter I guess.  I am coding it into the emit event but I don't know where else it needs declaration. I copied your code, so I don't know where else I need to declare.